# Show that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin n^\pi$ does not exist.

Tags: calculus

The question in the title is asked by an undergraduate student, and a general version is $\sin n^p$ diverges for any $p>1$.

For the case of $0<p<1$, it is clear by using the fact $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}((n+1)^p-n^p)=0$. Weyl's equidistriibution criterion can be applied here while I do not feel it is proper for an undergraduate student, see (4) of 
[The limit of $\sin(n^\alpha)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526857/the-limit-of-sinn-alpha).

For the case of $p$ rational, please see [$\sin (n^2)$ diverges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373322/sin-n2-diverges).

Someone said that I did not show my work. Actually I tried to use the approximation method but I failed.

For the case of $p$ irrational, we may assume that there exists a rational sequence $\{p_i\}$, such that $\{p_i\}$ is monotone increasing, and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} p_i=p$.

First, we can choose $\hat{\varepsilon}=\frac{\varepsilon}{3\ln k_1 \cdot k_1^p}$, then there exists $M_1$, such that $\forall i>M_1$, 
$$|\sin k_1^{p_i}-\sin k_1^p|<|k_1^{p_i}-k_1^p|\leq \ln k_1\cdot k_1^p |p_i-p|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}.$$
Similarly, there exists $M_2$, such that $\forall i>M_2$, 
$$|\sin k_2^{p_i}-\sin k_2^p|<|k_2^{p_i}-k_2^p|\leq \ln k_2\cdot k_2^p |p_i-p|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}.$$
Therefore, $\forall \varepsilon>0$, $\exists K>0$, such that $\forall k_1, k_2>K$, $\exists M>0$, such that $\forall i>M$,
$$|\sin k_1^{p_i}-\sin k_2^{p_i}|\leq |\sin k_1^{p_i}-\sin k_1^p|+|\sin k_1^{p}-\sin k_2^{p}|+|\sin k_2^{p}-\sin k_2^{p_i}|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}.$$
Then there is a rational number $\frac{a}{b}=p_i$, such that $\{\sin n^{\frac{a}{b}}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, which is a contradiction.

The problem here is that $i$ is depend on $k_1$ and $k_2$, therefore, we may not have $i$, such that  $\{\sin n^{p_i}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

However, I still want to find an easier way to answer a freshman in my class.

Comment: Do you know how to show $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin n$$ does not exists?

Comment: Yes. I know how to show $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin n^p$ does not exist for $p$ rational

Comment: And why can't you use the same proof?

Comment: The title does not much the body. And you should include such information in the question.

Comment: For example,  try $\sin (2n)^\pi$

Comment: Do you mean $\sin(2n^\pi)$, or $(\sin(2n))^\pi$.

Comment: I do not understand why some guys want to close this question, is it over too easy and I do not see it?

Comment: The reason is probably that you didn't show your work.

Comment: I mean $\sin((2n)π)$, in the proof of $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin n$ does not exist, we only need to try $\sin (2n)$ and get a contradiction. While in this case, you may need to try $\sin ((2n)^\pi)$.