# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos (n^3-n)$ converge or diverge???

Tags: sequences-and-series

I dont know how to solve this problem, please help! Thank you!

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos (n^3-n)$$

Comment: For an infinite series to (possibly) converge, it is necessary that the limit of the summand as $n\to \infty$ is equal to $0$. Does that happen here?

Answer (score 0):

It diverges. For a series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} a_n$, it is a necessary condition for convergence that $a_n$ is a zero sequence. Since

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos(n^3 - n)$$

doesn't exist because

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \cos(n^3-n) = \limsup_{n \to \infty}\cos n = 1 \neq -1 = \liminf_{n \to \infty} \cos(n^3-n),$$

the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(n^3-n)$ diverges.

Comment: The fact that the limit doesn't exist needs proof.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited my answer.

Comment: still needs work

Comment: Unfortunately that $\limsup$ answer is incomplete.   The assertion $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \cos(n^3-n) = \limsup_{n \to \infty}\cos n$ needs proof.  But do not give up: of course this is the correct way to show what the OP wants.

Comment: This is the kind of problem where the answer is super obvious, but where a proof is not completely straight forward. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509678/how-prove-this-lim-n-to-infty-sinnm-divergent ; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373322/sin-n2-diverges for possible approaches

Comment: Hi! i still don't understand how it diverges, sorry. is there any possible test or more straightforward proof to show that the series diverges?